# Convert.ToDouble for different CultureInfo values

Tags: c#, localization, converters, globalization

I need to convert values from string to double for different regions.

Lets's determine one thing:

- US culture uses strings that have `.` *dot* as pointer for decimal values
- European culture (ex. de-DE) uses strings that have `,` *comma* pointer for decimal values.

If you try to convert appropriate string values with `CultureInfo` specified using `Convert.ToDouble`function it will work just fine:

For US-en:

```
_value = Convert.ToDouble("1.5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat);  //gets 1.5
```

For DE-de:

```
_value = Convert.ToDouble("1,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat); //gets 1,5
```

But what if we need to convert value with `.` *dot* with European CultureInfo or the same goes for values with `,` *comma* with US CultureInfo ?

I'm asking this because I always use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat` and when languages are changed this will break. It makes more sense to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat` then using hard coded values such as
`CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")` or `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE")`.

This will break and will report an error:

For US-en:

```
_value = Convert.ToDouble("1,5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat); //because there is comma sign in 1,5
```

For DE-de:

```
_value = Convert.ToDouble("1.5", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE").NumberFormat); //because there is dot sign in 1.5
```

I tried to solve this by first converting Double values from one format to another Double temp = 1.5 to 1,5 for example, and then converting them to string but it does not work

There is solution where I can use String.Replace("","") function to replace `.` with the `,` and vice versa, but that is not the way I want things to be done

Comment: `It makes more sense to use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat then using hard coded values` - well, not really. You're saying you want to parse the value using the current culture. If you *know* what culture the value came from, you should pass that in. Hard-coding doesn't factor into the equation. You're essentially saying "Parse this value, treating periods as a decimal point, but I'll give you a value with a comma as the decimal point"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using CurrentCulture you need to set it as you know the culture like
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, but since I'm showing data in data table, I have to replace strings again with `String.Replace` since converted  data will be in different format. Values converted with `CultureInfo("en-US")` will have `.`-dots and values converted with CultureInfo("de-DE") will have `,`-commas in them.